# While updating url with Http PATCH request, does qnamaker gives answer to a query?

Tags: api, bots, azure-cognitive-services, azure-qna-maker

I am making the following PATCH request to published qanamaker endpoint:

```
{
  "update": {
    "urls": [
      "https://policies.google.com/faq?hl=en-US"
    ]
  }
}
```

Now it takes a few seconds to complete this request. (about 20-25 seconds) and more if there are more url's to update.

so if someone makes a POST request to qanamaker during this time, does it returns an answer?
And if Yes, then it returns it from new or old Knowledge Base?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update operation is Asynchronous so it will continue to perform other operations. It would return results from the old KB if someone performs operations while update is still processing.